# How can I have a function with a input-dependant output object name in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The objective was to create a Identity Matrix generator function.

```
def idmatrix(n):
  idnmatrix=[]
  ... #method to add rows and collumns with values
  return idnmatrix
```

For example, had I used

```
def idmatrix(2):
```

I would get as an output:

```
id2matrix
```

which would be:

```
id2matrix=[[1,0],[0,1]]
```

that goes for any "n" I'd like to be using:

```
id3matrix, id4matrix, etc...
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about what exactly you want your function to do? What do you *want* the input and output to be?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, it might be worth re-reading how Python handles objects. The name you give the object in the function is lost as soon as the function returns; it is not held by the object itself. If you want an object called `id2matrix`, assign the returned object to it in the calling class. i.e. `id2matrix = idmatrix(2)`

Comment: Besides the fact that @Trengot gives you a good hint, I just can't believe that's really what you want to achieve. How do you want to write the code which will make use of these auto-generated variable names? Your question is a good example of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I was looking for Python object name manipulation. As it seems, it doesn't exist, at least as I was expecting it, but got it solved with dictionaries, as other answer says.

Answer (score 1):

```
def idmatrix(size):
    matrix = [[0]*size for i in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        matrix[i][i] = 1
    return matrix

id1matrix = idmatrix(1)
id2matrix = idmatrix(2)
id3matrix = idmatrix(3)
id4matrix = idmatrix(4)
```

Comment: That function was just to exemplify, sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you return in a function does not have a variable name. In python variables and the objects they are mapped to are independent.
You can only manually set a variable name via calling your function:

```
ind2matrix = idmatrix(2)
```

However, what you could do instead is to create the matrix and its name alongside in your function:

```
def idmatrix(n):
    idnmatrix=[]
    ... #method to add rows and collumns with values
    return idnmatrix, 'id{}matrix'.format(n)
```

Where `'id{}matrix'.format(n)` is [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). For instance, `'id{}matrix'.format(2)` creates the string `'id2matrix'`.

Thus, your function now returns a `tuple`, where the first entry is the actual matrix and the second entry is the name of it.
Moreover, in order to collect many names and matrices you could put them into a dictionary. As a consequence, you have a mapping from the name to the value:

```
mat_dict = {}
for n in range(10):
    matrix, name = idmatrix(n)
    mat_dict[name] = matrix
```

thus `print mat_dict` would print something like this (not necessarily in this particular order):

```
   {'id3matrix': [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]],     
     'id2matrix': [[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]], 
     'id1matrix': [[1.0]], 
     'id0matrix': [], 
     ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me a way to do what I'm looking for. I was looking for some sort of dependance on objects and variables, but it seems that as you put it, the best way is to use dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return your matrix with that expected name you can use a dictionary to return the both, and you can use `numpy` to crate your identity matrix :

```
>>> def idmatrix(n):
...     return {'id{}matrix'.format(n):np.matrix(np.identity(n), copy=False)}
... 
>>> idmatrix(4)
{'id4matrix': matrix([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
                      [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])}
```

And with python you can use a nested list comprehension :

```
>>> def idmatrix(n):
...     return {'id{}matrix'.format(n):[[1 if j==i else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(n)]}
... 
>>> idmatrix(4)
{'id4matrix': [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]}
```

Comment: `[[3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3]]` isn't an identity matrix. refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix

Comment: Please don't name things `l` it's so easy to confuse with `1`, `I` etc

Comment: Thank you.
I was just looking for a method to relate objects and variables, not the matrix handling per se. (It was just the first example I though of using, while doing something related.)